# How to safely set a user specific environment variable for non-interactive ssh connections?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, environment-variables

I am setting up a unison based backup procedure.  The client is a Windows Server and the server is OS X 10.10 server.  I have a dedicated `backup-user` on the server that is allowed to connect through ssh.  The user is a service-only account so it's home folder doesn't include `~/Library` folder (and I don't want it to have one).  However unison expects to store the sync data in `~/Library/Application Support/Unison`.  Instead I need it to store this in `~/.unison`.

I can change this with an environment variable: `UNISON = ~/.unison`.  However since unison is calling a non-interactive ssh session, I can't reference this in `~/.bash_profile` (since it is not called on non-interactive sessions).

I can put it in `~/.ssh/environment` but then I need to set `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in my sshd_config, which I prefer not to do because of security concerns.

So the question is: How can I safely set a user environment variable that is available to non-interactive ssh sessions?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I gave up on this.  Instead I changed the location of the home folder of the `backup-user` to a location I did not mind containing the `Library/Application Support/Unison` folders.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help, but what about using `~/.profile`, which is sourced even for non-interactive sessions?

Based on this [answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be called for non-interactive sessions on my setup.  I have tried it with and without the sshd setting `PermitUserEnvironment yes`